# Display PDF stored on Amazon S3 with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

Im trying to display an attached pdf which is stored on Amazon S3 on the model's `show` view, but I can't get it to work.
So far my best attempt was to get the uploaded file's url on s3 like this :

```rb
#controller.rb

@key = upload.file.service_url
```

which successfully gets the URL of the file, and display it with iframe in the view. Which sadly doesn't work.

```
#view.html.erb

<iframe src=" <% @key %> " width="100%" height="500px">
```

It produces this:

[image: iframe]

My `Upload` model:

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :file
end
```

Thanks a lots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view.html.erb should be like this

```rb
#view.html.erb

<iframe src=<%= @key %> width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

This (" <% @key %> ") is a string for rails basically

Comment: I've already tried that but for some reason it escapes the @key.

Comment: I found the error!! It supposed to be ```<%= @key %>``` not ```<% @key %>```. I feel so dumb. Please edit your answer and I'll mark it as answered. Thanks :0

Comment: I also forgot to add = anyway. Edited